# How to validate russian email?

Tags: java, android

Generally i make simple validation with

```
   private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN =
      "^(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)])$";
```

The unicode flag is avaliably only from api 24

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN, Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

meanwhile in doccumentation stated that unicode characters already used

> /**
>        * Enables the Unicode version of *Predefined character classes* and
>        * *POSIX character classes* as eefined by [*Unicode Technical
>        * Standard #18: Unicode Regular Expression*](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/)
>        * *Annex C: Compatibility Properties*.
>        *
>
> *
>        * This flag has no effect on Android, unicode character classes are always
>        * used.
>        *
>        * @since 1.7
>        */
>       public static final int UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS = 0x100;

But when I am testing

```
String[] email = new String[] {
        "frakc@mail.ru", "frakc@mailru", "frakcmail.ru", "frakcru", "акфлс@ьфшд.кг", "акфлс@ьфшдкг",
        "акфлсьфшд.кг", "акфлскг",
    };
    for (String s : email) {
      Log.e("mcheck", "onCreate: " + s + " is valid " + Validator.getInstance().isValidEmail(s));
    }
```

Russian address does not pass validation

```
E: onCreate: ffff@mail.ru is valid true
E: onCreate: ffffc@mailru is valid false
E: onCreate: ffffcmail.ru is valid false
E: onCreate: ffffru is valid false
E: onCreate: акфлс@ьфшд.кг is valid false
E: onCreate: акфлс@ьфшдкг is valid false
E: onCreate: акфлсьфшд.кг is valid false
E: onCreate: акфлскг is valid false
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to validate the email address send them an email with a link to procedure with whatever you are doing.

There are several examples of this approach [here](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) and [here](https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643) with a discussion on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5763327)